# On the effectiveness of Sky Drop

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

So I was excited to try out Sky Drop, only to find that the "opponent was too heavy".

Is there a way of knowing this ahead of time, or do I have to memorize what's okay and what isn't? For instance, is it enough to say "if it kicks up a cloud of dust when it comes out, then it's too heavy, otherwise up we go"?

Comment: Weird, can't find an answer from googling, some people suggesting it's do to with level? Maybe try using it on a lower level but way heavier pokemon and a higher level, way lighter pokemon if possible?

Comment: Level 80 Aerodactyl against Level 35 Scolipede, failed. So... pretty sure it's based on weight :p

Comment: Definitely weight. Wonder if it's a simpler heavier than/lighter than check?

Answer (score 2):

According to Bulbapedia, which cites the *Pokémon X & Pokémon Y: The Official Kalos Region Pokédex & Postgame Adventure Guide*, Sky Drop will fail when used on a Pokemon weighing more than 440.9 lbs (200 kg).

Comment: Excellent. Now... how do I know if a 'mon is under 200kg? :D Is there anything that can be inferred from how it hits the ground when it comes into battle?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there may be a difference in the sound effect (a somewhat heavier thump) for pokemon heavier than 200kg but I don't have enough heavy pokemon to really tell. From the [relevant section](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Weight#441.0_lbs._to_451.4_lbs._.28200.1_kg_to_204.7_kg.29) of Bulbapedia's weight list, you can see that the immune pokemon all look very heavy but that's a rather unsatisfactory way to determine it.